# After Ledger 1.6 update and GUI Nitrogen Nebula upgrade, Can't open Nano wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger, hardware-wallet

In my low tech thinking, I upgraded to Nitrogen Nebula GUI and Ledger XMR v1.6.0 update. Now I can't get the Nano S wallet to open. Got an error 1:11415. There are other posts saying to go back to older versions. How? Please help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED THE PROBLEM!!!

Close Ledger Live while opening the GUI wallet.

Simple. Yay!

Comment: It does not fix it for me. I can not login anymore into my wallet. I Have the same application version 1.6 on ledger nano X and Monero gui v0.16.0.2
Please can someone help with this silly issue?